# Fix header during scroll

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on [this website](http://birsmatt.ch/gewerbe/), and as you can see I have a different header for different pages. In the other pages the header, the navigation, and the logo are fixed on top during scroll but not in [this page](http://birsmatt.ch/gewerbe/).

Is possible to fix them in this page as well via JS?

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the class of your dslc-header element to dslc-header-pos-fixed

```
<div id="dslc-header" class="dslc-header-pos-relative">
```

to

```
<div id="dslc-header" class="dslc-header-pos-fixed">
```